# Style Analyzers Suppression will not Target Tuple Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, suppress-warnings, stylecop

I have a method for which I would like to suppress some Visual Studio Code Analyzers' warnings, using a GlobalSuppressions.cs file.  I have used the IDE's built-in suppression code fixes to update said GlobalSuppressions.cs, but the warnings persist.  I noticed the method returns a tuple using the new [C# tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) feature.

**Expected behavior**

IDE message suppression tool adds a `SuppressMessage` annotation to the GlobalSuppressions.cs file which successfully suppresses the indicated warning.

**Actual behavior**

IDE message suppression tool adds a `SuppressMessage` annotation, but the return type of `Target` property is `System.` (e.g. `Target = "~M:Namespace.Class.Method(ArgType)~System."`).  This is obviously not the correct return type, and so the code analyzer does not suppress the message.

**Development environment**

Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.15 with [StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/)

**Steps to reproduce**

Make a method with tuple return type that violates a code analyzer's rule, e.g. lowercase method name when code analyzer expects capitalized method names.  Mine particularly is of the format

```
public static (bool Flag, string Reason) getFlag(Flaggable unit);
```

It violates

- SA1202, 'public' members should come before 'protected' members
- SA1300, Element should begin with upper-case letter
- SA1600, Elements should be documented
- IDE1006, Naming rule violation

**Attempted so far**

Am able to suppress the warnings in source with relevant `#pragma`s, but this is messy.  Have attempted to manually specify return type in `Target` property by using `System.Tuple{}` and `System.ValueTuple{}`.

**Bottom line**

Is there a way to suppress code analyzer warnings for methods with tuple return types?

Comment: Very clearly written and well researched. I think this should be filed as a bug. As you've noted, it didn't include the type name at the end of the `Target` property. Are you sure you added the type name in the right format?  Try using another close-constructed, 2-arity generic as a point of comparison. Since Visual Studio 2019 has been released, it's possible that it wouldn't be fixed for Visual Studio 2017. See if you can reproduce it in 2019 before filing a bug.

Comment: @madreflection thank you, I might end up doing that.